# How to copy field value into another field by its node ID?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a document that goes through 3 phases.  Each phase is its own content type because each phase brings in new questions and structure built upon the previous phase.

I want the below to happen when a user is adding new content for phase 2 & 3:

1. User is asked for node ID of previous document in phase 1
2. Field values from that previous node is retrieved and imported automatically into the new content's fields.

Are there any existing modules that can do this?  Maybe the Rules module?

Comment: it might be easier to hide the fields from phase 2 and 3 when entering the node information in phase 1, then hide phase 3 fields in phase 2, etc, than what you are trying to do with three separate content types, unless I am missing something here...

Comment: We tried using the Conditional Fields module to hide fields, but unfortunately it is too basic and cannot do "OR" conditions.  Instead I just had to re-think how I was doing my phases.  Solution is being posted below by me, but unfortunately it does not answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a solution to my problem, but I found a workaround.  Instead of 3 phases with each their own content types, I instead was able to make one content type and use the vertical tabs to create 3 "sections".  It is not ideal but it should work.  I would still like to know if what I am asking is possible.